# C#: Is there a way to launch the debugger from a codeline?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2012, mstest

Question:
Is it possible to start a **web project application** in my current solution without debugger (keycombo: Ctrl+F5) through a **codeline**?

thanks in advance

Comment: Recording `coded ui tests` doesn't require any special tricks to starting Visual Studio in debug mode. Best to give the documentation another once over.

Comment: Jeremy i know the basic stuff, thx anyway. My goal is it to test the actual web project in my solution. So i need to open the webproject in vs studio to record any stuff. And i want to automatize the click on "DEBUG-> Start without Debugging" before. Yes i asked in my question for debugging, but i forgot that you cant debug and record ui actions at the same time in this moment.

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

In your code to debug.

Comment: At first thx kuldip :) Hm i think i express myself in the wrong. I want to know how to start the web project in ms visual studio's page inspector in debug mode from a codeline :S

Answer (score 0):

The method KuldipMCA given is great, it can start debugger every time this code is executed. 
And there are another way, add an Assert into your code, this can enable you to attach debugger with some condition control. Such as:

```
//This will trigger an assert when the condition is false
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(obj != null);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's really useful when you are not in control of application with normal debugging.